# Airflow docker executing python script venv on windows

Tags: docker, airflow

I am new to airflow, when playing around with a dockerize airflow i am facing this problem.

**Enviroment**

***Windows (Host) ---> Share folder(venv python script) <---- Virtual Box VM Ubuntu (Guest) with Docker and Airflow container***

I am trying to execute a python script from a virtualenv (venv) in windows but i am not be able to achieve this. The package imports in the pyexcel.py script failes. Is it possible to workarounf this?

I've copied just the script into dags airflow dcoker container folder, but obviously is not working. How to deal with python virtual enviroments?

**DAG code**

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
dag = DAG('pyexcel', description='Inserting data into excel from python',
          schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20), catchup=False)

command = "C:/share_folder/python-project/Scripts/python.exe ~/dags/scripts/pyexcel.py"
task_1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='pyexcel',
    bash_command=command,
    dag=dag
    )

task_1
```

Answer (score 0):

In Airflow docker container Airflow expects the DAG file under /usr/local/airflow/dags location. So one way is to mount this folder to an external folder using docker volume mount https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

```
docker run --name scheduler 
-v /mnt/afdata/dags/:/usr/local/airflow/dags airflow
```